# Using a function from my main module in a required module

Tags: node.js, electron

To save space and to make my code more orderly I have isolated my template menu in a different file that is required in my main file; however I can't use any  function defined inside my main file in the module.

Is there a way to fix this besides creating a module export in the main file and requiring in the module?

menuTemplate.js:

```
[...]
let menuTemplate = [
  {
    label: 'File',
    submenu:[
      {label: 'New', click: () => {openfile()}}
    ]
  }
 [...]
```

main.js:

```
[...]
openfile() {
  // Do some stuff
}
[...]
```

I wonder whether there is a clean way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the easiest solution to my problem is to make my main functions called from the menu globals.